# How do I make a type that uses Batteries' Dyn_array in OCaml?

Tags: types, ocaml

For instance, suppose I want to make a type like this (using [Dyn_array](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/index.html)):

```
type some_type = SomeConstructor of <Dyn_array of integers>
```

I'm a little bit lost on how to do this though.  Could someone give me an example so I can wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem ? the syntax ?

Have you tried using an intermediate type ?

```
type my_dyn = Dyn_Array of int

type some_type = SomeConstructor of my_dyn
```

Comment: please note that i have batteries installed, but this is what i would do for a regular Stack, and it looks the same (based on the documentation though)

Comment: It was the syntax.  I actually found an answer for this, but forgot to post the answer here!

Answer (score 4):

(I don't have batteries installed). DynArray.t is defined already. You just want to specify the type for its free variable and not define a new constructor (what, `X of y` would do, well, aside from that embedded syntax being illegal),

```
type some_type = SomeConstructor of integers DynArray.t
```

If you wanted to leave the type of DynArray free then,

```
type 'a some_type = SomeConstructor of 'a DynArray.t
```